# Invoke imageView inside the edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-imageview

I have a class which extends EditText. Added the imageView inside the Edittext using following code

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0 ,R.drawable.email_button, 0);
```

I want to invoke the imageview onclick. Can anybody have an idea for this?

Thanks
Mindus

Answer (score 0):

It is not straightforward. You have set the declare an onTouchListener for your `EditText`, retrieve the drawable bounds and check if its bounds intersect the touch event

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          int rightCompundDrawableWidth = 0;
          Drawable drawable = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2/* right */];
          if (drawable == null) {
                return false;
           }
           rightCompundDrawableWidth = drawable.getBounds().width();
           if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
              && event.getX() >= (editText.getRight() - rightCompundDrawableWidth)) {
                    // clicked do something
                    return false;
          }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

this should be somehow do it. But it is kind of tricky. For the save of simplicity you could have an `EditText` and an `ImageView` wrapped into a horizontal `LinearLayout`, and set an `onClickListener` on the `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

You did not invoke a image view into EditText.
what you did is drawing a image on EditText.

You should write a component like

```
public class MyComponent extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener{

   private ImageView mImageView;
   private EditText mEditText;

   public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context,attrs)
      if(!isInEditMode)
      init();
   }

   public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, DefaultBlah blah){
      super(context,attrs, blah) // Other constructors... You should add them all.
      if(!isInEditMode)
      init();
   }

   private void init(){
      inflate(getContext(), R.layout.segment_mycomponent, this);
      mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
      mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

      mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
   }


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      int id = v.getId();
      if(id == R.id.image){
          // TODO Do your stuff here.
      }
   }


}
```

XML (segment_mycomponent)

```
<merge
   android:width = "wrap_content"
   android:height = "wrap_content">

   <ImageView
        android:id="+@id/image"
        android:width = "wrap_content"
        android:height = "wrap_content" />

   <EditText
        android:id="+@id/edittext"
        android:width = "wrap_content"
        android:height = "wrap_content" />
<merge/>
```

I wrote without IDE. Hope it compiles.

Good luck there.

Comment: I am getting nullpointer exception when we call mImageView at init() mtd and mEditText also null. MyClass extends MyComponent